# HTML5 Form Action Attribute

Tags: html, forms, methods, action

So I have to make a form, as usual I started by going 
`<form action=""`
and then I checked what action I have to use and it says :

> You must use explicit association.

Anyone got any idea what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I miss understood this. Explicit association ment to use Name and not
Name.
About the action we got told to just leave it for now ._.